# Python matplotlib changing the major unit scale of the x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, figure

I have a figure that isn't showing the correct dates on the x-axis. Possibly because there are too many observations to show and it results in not showing any. I am not sure if I should use the `set_xticks` function, but it gives me the attribute error

> AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'set_xticks'

My current code is this:

```py
def plot_w(dataframe,ticker,benchmark):

    # a. Printing highest observed values and corresponding date
    max1 = data_df.loc[:, ticker].max()
    max2 = data_df.loc[:, benchmark].max()
    max1_date = data_df[data_df[ticker] == max1]['Date'].values[0] 
    max2_date = data_df[data_df[benchmark] == max2]['Date'].values[0]
    print("The highest adjusted close price observed at: \n", ticker, ":", max1.round(2), "USD on the date ", max1_date, 
          "\n", benchmark, ":", max2.round(2), "USD on the date", max2_date)

    # b. Setting up plot based on dropdown input
    I = data_df.columns == ticker
    mpl_figure = dataframe.loc[:, ['Date',ticker,benchmark]]
    mpl_figure.plot(x='Date', y=[ticker,benchmark], style=['-b','-k'], figsize=(10, 5), fontsize=11, legend='true', linestyle = '-')
    plt.ylabel("USD",labelpad=5)
    plt.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=20)
    title = "Adjusted close prices for " + ticker + " and " + benchmark
    plt.title(title)
    plt.set_xticks(data_df['Date'].values) # Code fails here

# c. Creating the widget for the plot
widgets.interact(plot_w,
    dataframe = widgets.fixed(data_df),
    ticker = widgets.Dropdown(
            options=data_df.columns,
            value='ATVI',
            description='Company 1:',
            disabled=False,
        ),
    benchmark = widgets.Dropdown(
            options=data_df.columns,
            value='AAPL',
            description='Company 2:',
            disabled=False,
        )
)
```

The figure looks like this:
[image]

Comment: You forgot to show where you are using `set_xticks`

Comment: @Sheldore Added now.

Answer (score 0):

set_xticks is for an axis, if you are setting ticks for a figure it's

```
plt.xticks(data_df['Date'].values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can try the following inside your function working on an axis object. The idea is to first create an axis instance `ax`, and then pass it to the plot command. Later use it to set the x-ticks.

```
I = data_df.columns == ticker
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
mpl_figure = dataframe.loc[:, ['Date',ticker,benchmark]]
mpl_figure.plot(x='Date', y=[ticker,benchmark], style=['-b','-k'], ax=ax, fontsize=11, legend='true', linestyle = '-')
plt.ylabel("USD",labelpad=5)
plt.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=20)
title = "Adjusted close prices for " + ticker + " and " + benchmark
plt.title(title)
ax.set_xticks(data_df['Date'].values)
```

Comment: That makes sense to me, but when I replaced the code with one suggested I get the error. `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'`

Comment: @BlackBear: Without having [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), people will have hard time helping you here. At some point, they might give up answering. So please take some time to re-structure your question by including everything necessary to reproduce the error and the figure. That way you have more chances to get answers

Answer (score 0):

The *module* `matplotlib.pyplot` has no `set_xticks` function, but an `xticks` function instead. ([link to doc](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.html)). However, the *class object* `matplotlib.axes.Axes` does have `set_xticks` ([link to doc](https://matplotlib.org/2.2.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks)).

The easiest fix in your code is thus

```
plt.xticks(data_df['Date'].values)
```

Side note: I am not entirely sure why matplotlib.pyplot keeps around two functions with (almost) the same effect but different names. I guess allowing it to be called from either the module or the object is an imitation of MATLAB, but in MATLAB the function name is the same.

Comment: Using the line above returns the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'`

Comment: OK then, my attempt at "blind debugging" failed. Can you share a [minimum, complete and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) code sample? The one you give in your OP lacks the dataframe input data (and has a lot of irrelevant clutter).